# How do I map List values to a new objects properties

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enumerable

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Options { get; set; }
```

As you can see it takes a string as the `Key` and a collection of strings in the form of a list as the `Value`

And the goal is to create multiple objects of type `ProductVariant` which has 3 properties.
`Option1`, `Option2` and `Option3`

For each `Value` in the `Options` I want to set the `Option1` to the Option[0] value and then the `Option2` property gets the `Option[1]` value.

I tried doing something like this but it only gets one of the properies and it doesnt work because that's not what I was trying to accomplish.

```
foreach (var thing in item.Options.ElementAt(0).Value)
{
    variants.Add(new ProductVariant
    {
        Option1 = thing
    });
}
```

So bottom line.. I want to assign `Option1` and `Option2` to the corresponding values from the dictionary for each item in there.

Like this
[image]

How do I properly do this?

Comment: Your ProductVariant must have a property where the dictionnary is present.
Then you create 3 other property where the get give the correct index result of this dictionnary.
var test = new ProductVariant(yourDictionnary)
test.Option1
test.Option2
test.Option3

public string Option1 => _myDictionnary[0]; public Option2 => _my....[1] and so on

Comment: It can't since it's a third party library unfortunately.

Comment: So, every key in `Options` should have one corresponding `ProductVariant` item with values from dictionary values?

Comment: Yeah, just like how I tried describing it with the picture, I tried my best haha

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use reflection, like in the below example:

```
public class ProductVariant
    {
        public ProductVariant()
        {
            
        }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
        public string Option3 { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<ProductVariant> GetProductVariants(Dictionary<string, List<string>> options)
        {
            foreach (var optionList in options)
            {
                var pv = new ProductVariant();
                pv.Key = optionList.Key;

                var props = pv.GetType()
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Where(x=>x.CanWrite && x.CanWrite)
                    .Where(x=>x.Name!="Key")
                    .ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    props[i].SetValue(pv,optionList.Value[i]);
                }

                yield return pv;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tested this method and is working. You still need to put some validation to avoid errors.

you can see the method here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KCKhaS